# Abusing the word "library"

Tags: version-control, build-process, dependencies

I see a lot of questions, both here on SO and elsewhere, about "maintaining
common libraries in a VCS".  That is, projects foo and bar both depend on
libbaz, and the questioner is wondering how they should import the source
for libbaz into the VCS for each project.

My question is: WTF?  If libbaz is a library, then foo doesn't need its
source code at all.  There are some libraries that are reasonably designed
to be used in this manner (eg gnulib), but for the most part foo and bar
ought to just link against the library.

I guess my thinking is: if you cut-and-paste source for a library into
your own source tree, then you obviously don't care about future updates
to the library.  If you care about updates, then just link against the
library and trust the library maintainers to maintain a stable API.

If you don't trust the API to remain stable, then you can't blindly
update your own copy of the source anyway, so what is gained?

To summarize the question: why would anyone want to maintain a copy of a
library in the source code for a project rather than just linking against
that library and requiring it as a dependency?

If the only answer is "don't want the dependency", then why not just
distribute a copy of the library along with your app, but keep them
totally separate?

Comment: Could you format this to be more readable?

Comment: Also, make a note that you're talking about languages such as C. In languages like PHP or Ruby it would make a lot of sense to have an external library be part of your project. Also, Git has the concept of "submodule" which helps a lot with this.

Comment: I just formatted the text and got 75%. But it's more readable now.

Comment: Do PHP and Ruby not allow modules to be imported like Perl and Python do?  Surely they have a mechanism for this sort of thing?

Comment: @William, there are possibilities, but all sorts of incompatibilities appear. And your library's users want something that works out of the box. And there are some other cases, when one library depends on "something" more recent, while another cannot work with that recent "something"? What should the user do at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of vendor branches to control 3rd party dependencies is [discussed in some depth](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) in the Subversion book. As I understand it, the basic advantages are **guaranteeing** a stable API and uniformity of libraries for all developers, and the ability to control custom modifications in house in the same versioning system.

Comment: You can guarantee a stable API by not installing newer versions of the library.  If you want to do custom modifications, then you should fork the library.  Trying to manage dependencies with a VCS like this is strikes me as a bit insane.

Comment: Forking the library means you forgo all future improvements.  Using a vendor branch means you keep your modifications while still getting more recent versions of the vendor code.  This can cause problems, but I don't know of a better way to maintain user mods on top of a changing library.

Answer (score 1):

On the project I'm working on right now, we've got the main code (which is in one Subversion project) and a host of assorted libraries from various places that are in their own Subversion modules.  The Visual Studio solution maintains separate projects for each of them and links them together at the end.  If we were working on Unix or similar OSs, we'd do the same thing.

The only downside I see is that I sometimes forget to update one of the libraries that changes more frequently, and my code doesn't compile until I notice that.  If we had the libraries in the same module, then we wouldn't have that problem.  (Not that I'd ever do it that way.  The gains in flexibility and the ability to use different libraries with different main projects are just too great.)

The API is a red herring here:  either it stays the same or it changes, and if it changed we'd have to update the main code either way.  So is the question of source vs. binary libraries (either we compile them with the main project, or we don't).